# Printer outputting seemingly useless strings

Tags: dell, printer, shared-printers

Simple printing setup.  3 machines, 2 printers.  One prints invoices, other prints misc documents.

We use $300-400 range dell laser printers.   Usually they work great.  3 times now, we have replaced the printers with the same and different models. Often going to the next model up or newer.

For no noticeable reason, A printer will start acting up.  Test pages and documents output gibberish.  Sometimes hundreds of pages that don't stop until we power cycle.  Regardless of the spooler queue.

Reinstalling printer and drivers do not help.  Due to wiring constraints, the printers are each attached via USB and shared over the network.

Any ideas?

[image: gibberish]

Answer (score 2):

Please change the printer driver you are using. Those issue is because the language the driver use is not recognized by the printer.

Its like using a postscript driver for a printer that does not support postscript.

If all drivers does not work try with a basic hp laserjet 4 driver, even if its a dell, as the basic pcl language was born on that model. If that model does not work too it then can be the formatter board, this is the hardware that receive and translate the printout in the printer.

Comment: Both printers are the same.  Both drivers are the same.  Both were working yesterday, one at this very moment just ran out of paper because it started printing endless gibberish without any jobs.  Why would dell's reccomended driver be an issue on only one?  And randomly start acting up.

Comment: @James Check the last part I talk about the formatter board, so a warranty call

Comment: I'll try alternative drivers.  These printers do get a severely heavy load.  I have always assumed hardware issue, but with this new one acting up.  I have to cover my bases.  Thanks